# Is it safe to post dxdiag on the internet?

Tags: windows, data-leakage

Is there any information that might be useful to damage me on the dxdiag.txt file generated by windows 7?

A technical support forum from a big company (I guess they know what they're doing) asks me to paste the contents of the file in the forum, for them to understand if my problem is caused by something in my system.

Said posting is visible to everyone on the Internet and it worries me a bit.

Comment: Possible issues: It tells people alot about your system configuration (including PC name, your username on the PC,  BIOS version, PC model, webcams, connected USB devices, keyboards, mouses) all of which *may* be used by an attacker to find out to do whether your hardware has some (known) firmware issues which may be exploitable, so ranking you higher as a potential attack target (because it's easy?)

Comment: @SEJPM It could also be considered a privacy issue, depending on how sensitive you are about your BIOS version.

Comment: I would namely seek to hide non-private IP addresses (addresses other than those starting with "10." or "192.168." or "172.16." through "172.31.", and IPv6 addresses start with "fd"), usernames, or any other personal info (like your actual name).  If such things aren't in the report, then it is *probably* safe.  However, the only way to really be sure is to fully determine what is in the report, and analyze whether or not you think all of that is okay.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TLDR: It's probably fine, and MS meant it not to leak anything important.

It's worth stepping through this line by line, but it's too long. So let's leave out anything that's fairly innocent.

Essentially though, an attacker must work out what your system is (and this has no obvious Personally Identifying Information), and somehow find a specific driver of OS exploits. It's probably too much work to be worth it for most.

- System Information: Mostly innocent. Machine name and exact OS version's there. If someone knew how to get to your system in the first place, and there was a specific issue with that version... maaaybe.
- DxDiag Notes: Mostly innocent
- DirectX Debug Levels: Nothing that seems to be problematic here. Mine gives no useful information.
- Display Devices, sound devices, video capture devices, DirectInput devices, System Devices: Driver versions I guess. Driver versions are useful for troubleshooting, so its needed here. If someone knew how to get to your system in the first place, and there was a specific issue with that version of the driver, maaaybe
- Disk & DVD/CD-ROM Drives: As above, and how much space you have used.
- Preferred DirectShow Filters, Media Foundation Transforms,Media Foundation Enabled Hardware Categories,Media Foundation Byte Stream Handlers, Media Foundation Scheme Handlers, Preferred Media Foundation Transforms
  Disabled Media Foundation Transforms
  Disabled Media Sources: ALL TEH CODECS. Probably completely useless to anyone.
- EVR Power Information: enhanced video renderer information. Nothing much here, I think.
- Diagnostics: what's crashed or been troublesome. Looks like this, it's handy:

  ```
  +++ WER7 +++:
  Fault bucket 120429940662, type 4

  Event Name: APPCRASH

  Response: Not available

  Cab Id: 0



  Problem signature:

  P1: pa.exe

  P2: 0.0.0.0

  P3: 5626c8a1

  P4: KERNELBASE.dll

  P5: 10.0.10586.162

  P6: 56cd45b4

  P7: e06d7363

  P8: 0000000000071f28

  P9: 

  P10:
  ```

On the whole? Not too likely.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how paranoid you want to be. The dxdiag.txt file generated by using the Direct X Diagnostic utility will contain a lot of information about your computer and depending on the type of user you are, one particular thing may directly identify you (if you're the kind of person to name your PC Zachiel-PC).

For example:

- NETBIOS name of your machine
- Exact build number of your operating system
- Driver versions for a variety of drivers

But in general, no, you should be OK uploading this file to the internet.

Answer (score -1):

From technical perspective, it's probably OK. From social engineering perspective, however, such information could be useful to some extend.